# How to remove b symbol in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to remove `b` symbol from python3 script?

```
import subprocess

get_data=subprocess.check_output(["df -k | awk '{print $6}'"],shell=True)
data_arr=get_data.split()
data_arr.pop(0)
data_arr.pop(0)
for i in data_arr[:]:
    print(str(i))
```

Output

```
b'/dev/shm'
b'/run'
b'/sys/fs/cgroup'
b'/'
b'/tmp'
b'/test'
b'/boot'
b'/home'
b'/var'
b'/mnt/install'
b'/mnt/snapshot'
b'/mnt/share'
b'/mnt/storage'
b'/mnt/linux'
b'/mnt/download'
b'/run/user/1001'
```

Comment: How are we to know what you mean, friend?

Comment: I see: the `b` prefix `check_output` returns when it returns result as binary. Just decode the bytes to string, then.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre. Bytes, not binary.

Comment: Thanks for fast respond to all. I edit post to see output. How to convert binary string to string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `b` symbol indicates that the output of `check_process` is a `bytes` rather than a `str`. The best way to remove it is to convert the output to string before you do any further work on it:

```
byte_data=subprocess.check_output(["df -k | awk '{print $6}'"],shell=True)
str_data = byte_data.decode('utf-8')
data_arr=str_data.split()
...
```

The `decode` method will take care of any unicode you may have in the string. If your default encoding (or the one used by `awk` I suppose) is not `UTF-8`, substitute the correct one in the example above.

Possibly an even better way to get around this issue is to tell `check_output` to open `stdout` as a text stream. The easiest way is to add a `universal_newlines=True` argument, which will use the default encoding for your current locale:

```
str_data = subprocess.check_output(["df -k | awk '{print $6}'"], shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
```

Alternatively, you can specify an explicit encoding:

```
str_data = subprocess.check_output(["df -k | awk '{print $6}'"], shell=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

In both of these cases, you do not need to decode because the output will already be `str` rather than `bytes`.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is fantastic solution. Have a nice long weekend and Easter to all

Answer (score 0):

from my SO question:

```
read_key = ["binary", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(read_key, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8')
output = proc.communicate()[0]
print(output)
MY_EXPECTED_OUTPUT_STRING
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide to encoding parameter to check_ouptut to remove all the b (byte format)

for example:

```
import subprocess

get_data=subprocess.check_output(["df -k | awk '{print $6}'"],shell=True, encoding='utf-8')
data_arr=get_data.split()
data_arr.pop(0)
data_arr.pop(0)
for i in data_arr[:]:
    print(str(i))
```

Encoding paramater for [check_output()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) is available from Python 3.6

Answer (score -2):

try this:
a=str(yourvalue,'utf-8')